# Accumulate text variables in SAS across observations

Tags: sas

This seems straightforward, but it's not working as expected:

```
data names;
    input name $12.;
    cards;
John
Jacob
Jingleheimer
Schmidt
;
run;

data names;
    length namelist $100.;
    set names end=eof;
    retain namelist;
    if _n_=1 then namelist=name;
    else namelist = namelist || "|" || name;
    if eof then output;
run;
```

I would expect the result to have one observation containing

> John|Jacob|Jingleheimer|Schmidt

but `namelist` is just `John`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to trim the whitespace before concatenating to your list.

```
data names;
    length namelist $100.;
    set names end=eof;
    retain namelist;
    if _n_=1 then namelist=trim(name);
    else namelist = trim(namelist) || "|" || trim(name);
    if eof then output;
run;
```

You could also use the cats() function (which does the trimming and concatenation for you):

```
data names;
    length namelist $100.;
    set names end=eof;
    retain namelist;
    if _n_=1 then namelist=name;
    else namelist = cats(namelist,"|",name);
    if eof then output;
run;
```

Comment: Aha, thanks! Can you explain why? Is there padding of the text that's causing it to fill the available space or something?

Comment: Sure - according to this link (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001336080.htm) "When a character value is shorter than the length of the variable to which it belongs, SAS pads the value with trailing blanks.".  They go into a bit more detail if you look at the headings talking about concatenation and removing interior blanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you added STRIP to your assignment

```
strip(namelist) || "|" || name
```

it would work also

(but CATS is a really good solution)

Answer (score 0):

Using the catx function allows you to specify the delimiter...

```
data names;
    length namelist $100.;
    set names end=eof;
    retain namelist;
    namelist = catx("|",namelist,name);
    if eof then output;
run;
```